# Problems with multiple instances of an back-end java application with a Firebase Listener

Tags: java, spring, firebase, docker, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working in a back-end java application (using Spring) which is running in docker. This application have a Firebase RealTime Listener. Locally it works perfect! But when I deploy it in Docker and create 2 instances (containers) it start to run 2 times the same logic when I make a change in Firebase RTDB (it should be executed only once). This is the code that I have in a Bean to create the listener:

```
FirebaseOptions options;
  options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
      .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream(resourceDir + File.separator
          +"test1.json"))
      .setDatabaseUrl("https://test1.firebaseio.com/").build();

  FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

  final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  DatabaseReference listenerRef;
  DatabaseReference commerceRef;
  commerceRef.orderByChild("got").equalTo(0).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

        LOGGER.info("data changed:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
        LOGGER.info("data ref:" + dataSnapshot.getRef());
        ......logic ....

        } catch (Exception e) {
          LOGGER.info("Error en recepcion de actualizaciones de firebase" + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
      }


      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        LOGGER.error("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
      }

      @Override
      public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot arg0, String arg1) {
        LOGGER.info("Uno de los hijos fue modificado");
      }

      @Override
      public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot arg0, String arg1) {
        LOGGER.info("Uno de los hijos fue reubicado");
      }

      @Override
      public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        LOGGER.info("Uno de los hijos fue removido");
      }
    });
```

Is there any way to make it works once, even it has 2 instance? If not, what should I do? (Using only one container it's not a valid solution - due to high availity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase SDK would have no way of knowing if there are multiple instances of itself running and coordinate between them.  What you are seeing is the expected behavior.  If you want just one thing listening to a location in the database, you need to have only one instance, or you need to do this coordination yourself in a complicated way using transactions.  There is a node project called [firebase-queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) that effectively performs this coordination, if you would like to duplicate its logic.

But if you have backend logic that needs to run once per change in a database, you're probably far better off using [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to manage that.